# Order NSMutableDictionary for use with UITableView Where key is used in section header

Tags: uitableview, swift, nsmutabledictionary

I have a NSMutableDictionary that I use with a UITableView, in the table each section header is the value of a key and the cells for each section is derived from the key's value (an array).

I would like the table view to have a specific key at the top and am not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: Are you using Objective-C or Swift?

Comment: May I ask if there's a specific reason you're using `NSMutableDictionary` instead of Swift's `Dictionary`?

Comment: I didn't think there was much of a difference when I started this app, I'm not sure if there is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest changing your data structure to an array of custom "TableSection" objects.  Each object would have a header property and an array of values for the cells.

Storing the "TableSection" objects in a mutable array lets you order them whatever way you need.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary (NSDictionary or Swift Dictionary) is not suitable for storing the contents of a table view. Dictionaries are inherently unordered, and a table view must have its contents presented in a consistent order.

You can certainly use an array of dictionaries. That's pretty common. For a sectioned table view an array of arrays of dictionaries is quite common (outer array has an entry for each section, and inner array has an entry for each row in a given section.)

If you have special contents to go in the section header you can create a section object that has a header object an an array of row objects (dictionaries or custom "row" data objects), and then have an array of section objects. Then you make your data source methods serve up cells using whatever data structure you come up with.

Comment: Oh. I just reread @PhillipMills suggestion. He said the same thing I did. Great minds think alike it seems. :)